# Return false; does not work in jquery .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before posting this question I tried StackOverflow but did not find the answer.

So, the question is, I have an array with some values(suppose 4,6,7,8,10 etc). I used the .each function of jquery to prompt the alert message. but my code gives me an alert message, focus to the desired input box and submit the form and does not "return false". 
I want it to return false after focusing.

```
$(document).on('keypress','#create_invoice',function(){
$.each(newArr, function( i, l ){
//alert( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
if($.trim($('#item_name'+l).val()).length == 0)
        {
          alert("Please Enter Item Name");
          $('#item_name'+l).focus();
         // return false; //if use this not work and submit form
        }
//return false; //if use this not work and submit form
});
//return false; if i use this then submit() not work
$('#invoice_form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return false works, but I think what you want is to stop the form from submitting if you returned false. That behavior can be done with this;

First put an `e` in the function argument then use `e.preventDefault();`.

What's next is make a variable that would be a boolean which would determine if you can allow the form to submit. In the code below, I used `var allowSubmit`.

Try the code below.

```js
$(document).on('keypress', '#create_invoice', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // boolean variable
  var allowSubmit = true;

  $.each(newArr, function(i, l) {
    if ($.trim($('#item_name' + l).val()).length == 0) {
      alert("Please Enter Item Name");
      $('#item_name' + l).focus();

      // set the variable to false
      allowSubmit = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // check if we could submit the form
  if (allowSubmit) {
    $('#invoice_form').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked for me, I remove the 2nd "return false" which is after the if condition, and it works fine in my case.

Comment: Ah yeah! The first `return false;` is enough to stop the loop. Updated the answer to accommodate that. Do accept this answer if it's the solution. Thanks.